# Adding a button and image using Zend Framework in Codeigniter

Tags: zend-framework, codeigniter, barcode

I want to generate a barcode and underneath a button so that the user can just click it and then print. However I haven't been able to do this so now I have this code:

```
$page = new Zend_Pdf();
$imageResource =  Zend_Barcode::draw('code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions);
imagejpeg($imageResource, 'barcode.jpg', 100); 
$img = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath('barcode.jpg'); 
    //echo $randomTxt;
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<img src="'. base_url() .'/images/logo.png"/>';
    echo '<img src="'. $img .'"/>';
```

However I get the following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Object of class
>   Zend_Pdf_Resource_Image_Jpeg could not
>   be converted to string
>
> Filename:
>   views/vista_codigoDeBarras.php
>
> Line Number: 19

I have no idea how to accomplish what I need and it's sort of urgent now =/ any idea how I can do it? I'm using Zend framework to generate de barcode within CodeIgniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused on what you're trying to achieve, but `Zend_Pdf_Image` is made for adding images to PDF documents. Given your requirement:

> I want to generate a barcode and
>   underneath a button so that the user
>   can just click it and then print.

There are a few ways you can accomplish this. First off is to create a php script that simply outputs a barcode image, and use that as the `src` attribute of the image:

```
// Only the text to draw is required
$barcodeOptions = array('text' => 'ZEND-FRAMEWORK');

// No required options
$rendererOptions = array();

// Draw the barcode in a new image,
// send the headers and the image
Zend_Barcode::factory(
    'code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions
)->render();
```

Source: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.barcode.creation.html

The user can then just open the image in a new tab or download and print it.

The other option is to offer them a PDF download, which is a bit more complicated than I can devote the time to providing sample code for, but this link explains how to generate PDFs using the `Zend_PDF` class:

http://devzone.zend.com/article/2525

Comment: The thing is they requested for a button along with the PDF that allows for them to just click and bring up the print dialog. and I havn't been able to accomplish that

Comment: @Luis The only way I could think of remotely accomplishing that is to open a popup with just the barcode image and calling `window.print()` in it. You might be able to do the same thing with an embedded pdf, but I'm not sure if those are included in `window.print()` calls. Also many browsers disable printing included images by default. I'd just have a PDF download and let the user print it, but that's not up to me unfortunately :/

Comment: how can I call the window.print() so that it affects the child window instead of the one that triggers the new window to open?

Comment: @Luis The popup window will just load an HTML page, so you just need to have the call in the popup HTML's `window.onload` call. Also remember that popups should be linked to a user action, such as the button press you mentioned. Failure to do so leads to nasty issues with popup blockers.

Comment: the thing is that using the Zend_Barcode::factory... etc, won't allow the next page to load ANYTHING else, that's why I can't get it to load a button, or image or even javascript =/

Comment: @Luis you need to make a stand alone PHP page that generates the image using `render()`, so the proper image headers get sent, then source it in the `<img>` tag of the popup window.